# What is the meaning of "praise someone's head off"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Your note just came and am utilizing a good hangover to answer it. I
> was not annoyed at anything you said (You surely know by now, I’ve
> written it often enough, how much I admire your work). I was only
> annoyed at your refusal to accept the sincere compliment G. Stein was
> making to you and instead try and twist it into a slighting remark.
> She was **praising her head off** about you to me when you came up she
> started to repeat it and then at the end of the praise to spare you
> blushes and not be rude to me she said that our flames (sic) were
> maybe not the same—then you brood on that—

This is the first paragraph of Ernest Hemingway's letter to F. Scott Fitzgerald. I looked up the dictionary for the phrase "head off" but still don't understand what does "praising her head off" mean in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiom is listed under 'one's head off' in some dictionaries.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yell%20her%20head%20off)

> one's head off (idiom)
>
> : very loudly or without restraint
>
> She had to shout her head off to get her friends attention at the
> concert.
>
> He is shy at first, but will talk your head off [=will talk
> continuously] once you get to know him.
>
> You can yell your head off at him, but he still won't listen.
>
> They will be laughing their heads off when they see my costume.

[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/84896?rskey=8i9YOL&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid1842795):

> to —— one's head off: to —— with great vigour or intensity, at great
> length, etc., esp. to the point of weariness or exhaustion.
>
> 1890   C. C. Harrison Anglomaniacs ii. 79   What man wants to work his
> head off to lay up money, and then see a fool and profligate walk away
> with it?
>
> 1951   J. Cornish Provincials 11   As term progressed, Saturdays and
> Sundays..we would sit in our den..talking our heads off.
>
> 1985   J. Howker Nature of Beast i. 21   We spent this pretty
> miserable day..not talking much, just smoking our heads off.
>
> 2010   C. Grant Teenie ix. 91   Those girls look like straight-up
> groupies, screaming their heads off and trying to touch Greg.